# Passing a parameter between views in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to accomplish something like this:

I am creating a simple blog. I have set up categories for my blog.
I want that when my user goes to posts/index, he sees a list of all categories.

Example:
Text
Image

Upon clicking on a category, my user gets redirected to the posts/new page, where the category_id field will by transmitted through a hidden_field.

So my code right now is:

in posts/index

```
<% @categories.each do |c| %> 
  <%= link_to c.name, new_post_path(:category => c.id) %><br />
<% end %>
```

and in my posts/_form i'm trying to do something like this

```
<%= f.hidden_field :category_id, :value => params[:category_id] %>
```

which is not working though, because the html output is

No value is being passed.

What is the correct way to proceed here?
Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance it looks like a simple mistake mixing up the param names category and category_id.

Try this:

```
<% @categories.each do |c| %> 
  <%= link_to c.name, new_post_path(:category_id => c.id) %><br />
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, from what i can understand in your code, it seems a post belongs to a category. In such case, you could nest routes from one in another, and paths for creating nested object would become accessible, such as new_category_post(@category).

The routing would look like that:

```
resources :categories do
  resources :posts
end
```

You can read about this matter here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html